# Swift: how to make a background function that keeps running even when I switched to a different view controller

Tags: ios, swift

I'm making an app which has socket connection to a local server, I need a background function to send heartbeat signal to the server constantly to maintain the connection even when I switched to different view controllers.  How can I do that? (I don't want to create a background function that I can call in every view controller, I just want this function to keep running)

Comment: kindly mark the answer as correct. if it helped you :) It will help others too

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I hope you have a separate class for controlling socket connection right?

ok now create an instance of that class in your AppDelegate.

```
var yourInstance = YourSocketClass()
```

now create a reference to the app delegate in all view controllers where you want to use

```
  let app_delegate = UIApplication.shared.delegate as! AppDelegate
```

now you can use anywhere like this `app_delegate.yourInstance`

It will keep running the same instance and you will not have to create new instance everytime you change view controllers

Comment: Thanks, it works. After testing, what surprise me is, just simply call a background function will work, it will continue running between viewcontrollers.